# How can I calculate the area of a circle centered at (2,2) with radius 2 using double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is what the graph loosk like.

Obviously I know $\pi r^2$ but if I specifically wanted to find the area using double integrals in polar coordinates, how would I go about it?

My guess is that $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$

and for $r$ I need to do:

$(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=4$

$x^2-4y+4+y^2-4y+4=4$

$(x^2+y^2)-4(x+y)=-4$

$r^2-4(r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta)=-4$

$r^2=4(r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta)-4$

Not exactly sure what to do from here.

Comment: I don't think the step from second last to final line is correct.

Comment: I think you mean radius $2$.

Comment: @J.G. yep sorry I'll change that now

Comment: @coffeemath Did I make a computational error?

Comment: are my bounds for $\theta$ correct?

Comment: @user130306 Tou moved over the term in parentheses to the other side and correctly changed its sign, however you for some reason replaced the $r \sin \theta$ by $4 \sin \theta.$

Comment: @coffeemath oh yea, that was an accident, I changed it to the correct form but what do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

Do the coordinate change :$$ x=2r\cos (\theta)+2 \\y=2r\sin(\theta)+2\\r\in [0,1] \;\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$. Note that it verifies $r^2=1$ so it is just a traslation of the usual polar coordinates change. Be careful with the jacobian of the transformation, which is not $r$  but $4r$. So
$$A=\iint_C dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 4r\;dr\;d\theta=4\pi$$ as expected.

Comment: not really sure how you were able to get this integral. How would I go about doing this the normal way? Because I wouldn't think to do $x=2x+2$

Comment: I'm not doing x=2x+2, that does not make sense... I'm doing a change of coordinates that consists in a traslation and deformation of the usual polar coordinates change that only works for the unity circle.  Basically i'm transforming your circle into the unity circle centered at origin

Comment: Oh okay thanks. How did yoh get the jacobian? J

Comment: If x and y are two functions in the variables r and $\theta$, the jacobi matrix is the matrix by columns formed by the gradient of x and y. So the jacobian is the absolute value of its determinant

Answer (score 1):

After getting $r^2=4(r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta)-4$ you can solve for $r$ to get $r_{1,2}(\theta) = 2\left(\sin\theta+\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}\right)$

The two solutions are the two intersections of the ray from the origin with the circle:

[image]

When using polar coordinates, the area can be obtained as $\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b r^2(\theta)\;d\theta$

So in this case you'll need to calculate

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}r_1^2(\theta)\;d\theta - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}r_2^2(\theta)\;d\theta \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}(r_1^2(\theta)-r_2^2(\theta))\;d\theta\\
& =  8 \int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)\sqrt{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}\;d\theta
\end{align}

which, after some calculations, gives $4\pi$.